# How to access a two-level objected using variables?

Tags: php, object, mapping

Example objects:

```
$this->obj1->lvl1
$this->obj1->lvl1->lvl2
```

I know I can access objects like this:

```
$var = 'obj1';
$this->{$var}
```

But I want to go further. The problem is that it needs to be dynamic so the name needs to come from a string. I'm using this for mapping. So a user can use dot notations to access anything in the object. So if the user uses this notation:

```
'obj1.lvl1'
'obj.lvl1.lvl2'
```

So all I have to do is:

```
$this->obj1->{$mapped_string}
```

So `$mapped_string` can go either one level or two or more levels deep.

It will map directly to the object. Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string into accessors, and then drill down in a loop. This works for any length of accessors:

```
$obj = $this;
$accessors = explode('.', $mapped_string);
foreach ($accessors as $acc) {
    $obj = $obj->{$acc};
}
var_dump($obj);
```